# Why does my Samsung galaxy blaze randomly shut off and won't reboot until it is plugged into the wall?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

My galaxy blaze phone randomly shuts off (even though I have plenty of battery life left) while using it and then tries to reboot itself but never fully starts up. Therefore, it constantly keeps shutting off and on until I charge it.  While it is turning off and on I take out the battery for several minutes but nothing seems to work.  Once it plugs into the wall it starts to work again but lately this is happening more and more often, up to 5 times a day.

Would a new battery or update fix this or is it something malfunctioning within the the phone itself?

Answer (score -2):

open setting choose backup and reset. Once that is done turn the phone on It should be as good a s new. I took this off T-mobile help thanks Tmobile

Comment: You should mention that this removes all installed applications and user data from the internal memory and should be used with caution!